# how to order dictionary of dataframes by length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to merge dataframes in a dictionary

```
example_dict = {key1: df1, key2: df2, ....}
```

each of the dataframes are of different row length, and all have a column called `id`

my plan was to do this:

```
merged_dfs = partial(pd.merge, on='id', how='inner')                                                              
master_merged_dfs = reduce(merged_dfs, example_dict.values())
```

The issue is that some dataframes have few ids, and some have many. if I do an inner join the issue is that eventually the final merged df will keep getting smaller.

I think the best way to go about this is probably order all the dataframes in the dictionary, then doing a left or right joing depending on if the ordering is ascending or descending.

I just dont know how I would do the ordering.

Comment: `inner` join doesn't care of order. At the end, you will only rows where `id` is common through all dataframes. It doesn't matter whether the data is sorted or not. Why don't you use `outer` join? Inner join is the intersection so the smallest common set rather than outer join is the union so the largest common set. It will be different if you choose `left` join (descending order) or `right` join (ascending order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the length of a `DataFrame` through its [shape](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shape.html), which you can use as a key to sort on:

```py
sorted_dict = dict(sorted(example_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].shape[0]))
```

This sorts the dictionary of `DataFrame`s by length **ascending**. If you prefer by length **descending**:

```py
sorted_dict = dict(sorted(example_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].shape[0], reverse=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python builtin function [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) and `len` as key function to get a list sorted in increasing length, and then do a right merge.

```
merged_dfs = partial(pd.merge, on='id', how='right')                                                              
master_merged_dfs = reduce(merged_dfs, sorted(example_dict.values(), key=len))
```